R unable to generate the same multiway contingency table output as SAS
I've asked a couple of colleagues who are experienced in r, for help in converting SAS code to r.  The challenge involves a multiway contingency table analysis, using a relatively simple data set. Although both colleague are veteran r users, they were independently, unable to generate output in r that even closely matched output from SAS -- leaving them both perplexed. Below are the Data and SAS output and the SAS program.  If anyone is up for a challenge in solving the r script for this...it would be much appreciated.

data new; 
input prey $ stage $ habitat $ number;
cards ; 
chr a l 69
chr j p 8
chr j l 43
chr a p 21
amp a l 29
amp j p 1
amp j l 19
amp a p 6
zoo a l 6
zoo j p 28
zoo j l 3
zoo a p 72
ost a l 10
ost j p 4
ost j l 6
ost a p 4
;

proc genmod data=new; 
class prey stage habitat/param=effect; 
model number=prey|stage|habitat / dist=poisson type3 wald;
output out=out p=p; 
run;

proc sort data=out; 
by prey stage habitat; 
run;

proc print data=out; 
run;

As mentioned previously, I'd asked two colleagues who are well-versed in r, to help solve a SAS-to-r conversion for a multiway contingency table analysis.  Neither colleague was able to generate results using r that were even closely similar to SAS.  I also conferred with a Senior Statistician at SAS, who corroborated my [SAS] results with his own analysis, where he used a number of different procedures. So the SAS output is correct.

Can you please provide the R code that the colleagues tried out?

By the way if I had a nickel for every time someone said "R cannot do X but SAS can" based on one or two people trying unsuccessfully to do something in R, ... well I wouldn't have that many nickels but I would have at least four or five.

to be fair to the OP, they didn't say "R can't do X", they said "I can't generate results in R that are close to SAS's". I wouldn't be surprised if there were something type-3-ANOVA-ish going on ... (see car::Anova(), although its idea of "type 3" is not identical to SAS's either)

FYI there is a typo in your SAS output, habitat is listed as having 3 df but should only have 1 as there are only two levels of habitat

@BenBolker fair enough, I guess I am just sensitive, having been in that position before :^D

"R unable" in title sounds like "R can't" but I presume they meant "We're unable in R..."

Given the answer I am voting to reopen.

I'd still love to see the tables given in text format, or with alt-text ...

Here's an identical result to the SAS code, making use of the joint_tests() function from the R package emmeans (thanks as always to Russ Lenth for creating the package, it's a lifesaver)! By the way, I was able to determine that SAS was doing joint tests by running the OP's code in SAS which gives the following message:

Note: Under full-rank parameterizations, Type 3 effect tests are replaced by joint tests. The joint test for an effect is a test that all the parameters associated with that effect are zero. Such joint tests might not be equivalent to Type 3 effect tests under GLM parameterization.

library(emmeans)

dt <- data.frame(
  prey = rep(c('chr','amp','zoo','ost'), each = 4),
  stage = c('a','j','j','a'),
  habitat = c('l', 'p'),
  number = c(69, 8, 43, 21, 29, 1, 19, 6, 6, 28, 3, 72, 10, 4, 6, 4)
)

fit <- glm(number ~ prey * stage * habitat, family = poisson, data = dt)

joint_tests(fit)

We get this output:
 model term         df1 df2 F.ratio  Chisq p.value
 prey                 3 Inf  16.844 50.532  <.0001
 stage                1 Inf  12.103 12.103  0.0005
 habitat              1 Inf   5.739  5.739  0.0166
 prey:stage           3 Inf   0.556  1.668  0.6439
 prey:habitat         3 Inf  28.608 85.824  <.0001
 stage:habitat        1 Inf   0.923  0.923  0.3368
 prey:stage:habitat   3 Inf   0.635  1.905  0.5925

SAS output screenshot for comparison:


Does that also supply a way to make the first table in the question?  I wasn't sure if that was part of what OP was asking.

@Elin I understood the OP's question to be more about reproducing the statistical analysis. But if you want to reproduce the first table you could do xtabs(number ~ habitat + stage + prey, data=dt) |> ftable(row.vars = 1:2)

qdread -- thank you for resolving my question. your r version worked perfectly!  Much appreciated.
